# Angular 2 : Handling click event for button

Tags: angular

I have 3 buttons. when I click on 1st button then its text and css gets changed and when I click on the same button then I get default css as before. I want this for all 3 buttons. I have tried this code.

```css
.add_btn{
border:thin red solid;
}
.added_btn{
border:thin black solid;
}
```

```html
<button class="{{add_btn ? 'add_btn' : 'added_btn'}}" (click)="add_btn = !add_btn">{{add_btn ? 'addded' : 'add'}}</button>
<button class="{{add_btn ? 'add_btn' : 'added_btn'}}" (click)="add_btn = !add_btn">{{add_btn ? 'addded' : 'add'}}</button>
<button class="{{add_btn ? 'add_btn' : 'added_btn'}}" (click)="add_btn = !add_btn">{{add_btn ? 'addded' : 'add'}}</button>
```

I can add multiple buttons by clicking on them.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Angular2+'s feature [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) as it can add or remove CSS classes from HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="added_btn" [ngClass]="{'add_btn' : add_btn}" (click)="add_btn = !add_btn">{{add_btn ? 'addded' : 'add'}}</button>
<button class="added_btn" [ngClass]="{'add_btn' : add_btn}" (click)="add_btn = !add_btn">{{add_btn ? 'addded' : 'add'}}</button>
<button class="added_btn" [ngClass]="{'add_btn' : add_btn}" (click)="add_btn = !add_btn">{{add_btn ? 'addded' : 'add'}}</button>

.added_btn{
  border:thin black solid !important;
}
```